# ADFS 2.0 for the users to access through intranet and inetrnet

Tags: adfs

I am developing an ASP.NET Web application which should be accessible to the users who can access from both intranet and internet. Could you suggest the approach to implement this with ADFS 2.0.
The requirement is when users are logged in in the intranet the authentication to the app should be seamless without giving user id and password. Whereas for the same users if they are accessing out side intranet it should take email id and password as creditentials and authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an ADFS proxy in front of ADFS for external users which by default uses Forms.

Internal users will get Windows Auth.

ADFS out-the-box only allows authentication with user name.

You would have to do some custom development - refer [Adjusting the Home Realm Discovery page in ADFS to support Email Addresses](http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2011/07/12/Adjusting-the-Home-Realm-Discovery-page-in-ADFS-to-support-Email-Addresses.aspx).